# Format something Inactive

Tags: output-formatting

```
ops = Map[Inactive, 

   Tuples[{Times, Plus, Subtract, Divide}, {4 - 1}], {2}];

rules = Thread[{a, b, c} -> #] & /@ ops;

matchQ[list_] := 

 Module[{}, 

  res = Fold[Replace[#1, List -> #2[[1]], {#2[[2]]}, Heads -> True] &,

  list, Transpose@{{a, b, c}, {1, 2, 3}}] /. rules //. 

    Inactive[Subtract][x_, y_] :> Inactive[Plus][x, -y];

  Select[res, Activate[#] == 24 &]]

list = {6, 4, 2, 3};

pattern = {{#[[1 ;; 2]], #[[3 ;; 4]]}, {#[[

 1]], {#[[2]], #[[3 ;; 4]]}}, 

    Reverse@{#[[1]], {#[[2]], #[[3 ;; 4]]}}, {{{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, #[[

  3]]}, #[[4]]}, Reverse@{{{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, #[[3]]}, #[[4]]}} &;

parts = Flatten[(pattern) /@ Permutations[list, {4}], 1];

res1 = matchQ /@ parts // Quiet // Flatten;
```

When I'm playing with a calculating 24, I used some function like `Inactive`.
My question is how can I make the output more reasonble in human writing habbit? For example, here I replace `Subtract` with `Plus`.

I want to change `((6+4)+-2)*3` to `((6+4)-2)*3`

`StringForm` is also OK, just for display

```
res1[[1]]

(*
    ((6+4)+-2)*3
*)
```

[image]

Comment: Is this what you're after: `MakeBoxes[Inactive[Plus][x__], StandardForm] := MakeBoxes[Plus[x], StandardForm]`?

Comment: @jkuczm thanks, yes, this works, `ToString[res1[[1]], FormatType -> StandardForm] // ToString` and this can give the string result.

Comment: @jkuczm please consider posting an answer, or HyperGroups, maybe self-asnwer?

Comment: @Kuba Answer posted, thanks for reminding me of this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own `...Form` wrapper that will format inactive elements as if they where active.

Let's start with a helper function, that we'll use in a [`TagBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagBox.html), to reinterpret expression created from active boxes, as inactive expression:

```
ClearAll[inactivateHead]
SetAttributes[inactivateHead, HoldAllComplete]
inactivateHead[head_[args___]] := Inactive[head][args]
```

Now our final `activeForm` wrapper, which locally overrides `MakeBoxes` for `Inactive`.

```
ClearAll[activeForm]
Options[activeForm] = {Editable -> True};
activeForm /: MakeBoxes[activeForm[expr_, opts : OptionsPattern[]], form_] :=
    Block[{Inactive},
        If[OptionValue[activeForm, {opts}, Editable],
            Inactive /: MakeBoxes[Inactive[head_][args___], f_] := 
                TagBox[MakeBoxes[head[args], f], inactivateHead]
        (* else *),
            Inactive /: MakeBoxes[Inactive[head_][args___], f_] := 
                InterpretationBox[#, expr] &@MakeBoxes[head[args], f]
        ];
        TagBox[MakeBoxes[expr, form], activeForm]
    ]
```

If you want to copy and paste output of `activeForm` and then edit what you pasted, set `Editable` option to `True`, then `TagBox`, with our `inactivateHead` function, will be used, to reinterpret expression from edited boxes as inactive expression, but this reinterpretation might not be completely accurate.

If you don't need to modify copy/pasted output of `activeForm`, you can use `Editable -> False`, then an uneditable [`InterpretationBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpretationBox.html) will be used.

To be able to convert `activeForm`-wrapped expressions to strings in arbitrary forms we can override `ToString` by setting `activeForm` up-values:

```
activeForm /: ToString[activeForm[expr_], rest___] := 
    Function[activeExpr,
        ToString[Unevaluated[activeExpr], rest],
        HoldAllComplete
    ] @@ (HoldComplete[expr] /. Inactive[x_] :> x)
activeForm /: ToString[expr_, activeForm, rest___] := 
    ToString[activeForm[expr], StandardForm, rest]
```

Finally add `activeForm` to `$OutputForms`:

```
If[FreeQ[$OutputForms, #, {1}],
    Unprotect @ $OutputForms;
    PrependTo[$OutputForms, #];
    Protect @ $OutputForms;
]& @ activeForm
```

An example inactive expression in `StandardForm` and `activeForm`:

```
tmpInactive = Inactive[Plus][Inactive[Subtract][1, 2], Inactive[Divide][6, 3], 4]
tmpInactive // activeForm
```

[image: activeForm]

Same expression converted to string in default `OutputForm`:

```
ToString[tmpInactive]
ToString[tmpInactive // activeForm]
```

[image: ToString]

in `InputForm`:

```
ToString[tmpInactive, InputForm]
ToString[tmpInactive // activeForm, InputForm]
```

[image: ToString InputForm]

in `StandardForm`:

```
ToString[tmpInactive, StandardForm]
ToString[tmpInactive // activeForm, StandardForm]
```

[image: ToString StandardForm]

and directly in `activeForm` which is equivalent to `activeForm` with `StandardForm`:

```
ToString[tmpInactive, activeForm]
```

[image: ToString activeForm]

All expressions given by OP (click on image to enlarge it):

```
res1 // activeForm
```

[image: res1 activeForm]