# Can one prevent $\TeX$ conversion from changing form of expressions?

Tags: output-formatting, latex, conversion

This is similar to my previous question [Can one prevent operators like `Factor` or `Apart` from changing full form of some algebraic expressions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98272/35000) but concerns $\TeX$ and I cannot figure out whether I might use the solution found there in this case. I found several questions here about $\LaTeX$ conversion, one of them ([Override Equation structure change in mathematica - CopyToLaTeX](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24416/35000)) addressing this particular issue, but the only relevant answer (using `HoldForm`) does not work in my case (see below).

When I export expressions to $\TeX$, some undesirable (for me) form changes occur. A minimal example is e. g. `(1+q+q^2)(1-4 q)` which goes to $(1-4q)(q^2+q+1)$. This happens both while right-clicking and choosing "Copy as" -> "LaTeX" or issuing `1-q+q^2//TeXForm`.

Doing `TeXForm[StandardForm[(1+q+q^2)(1-4 q)]]` helps only partially, it gives $(1-4q)(1+q+q^2)$, i. e. still interchanges the factors which I don't want to do.

In this particular case, `TeXForm[HoldForm[(1+q+q^2)(1-4 q)]]` helps, but I sometimes need to export really huge expressions where `HoldForm` does not work the way I want. For example, if I would have `Sum[q^n,{n,0,2}](1-4q)` instead (and I frequently have large expressions like that) then `TeXForm[HoldForm[Sum[q^n,{n,0,2}](1-4q)]]` gives $\left(\sum _{i=0}^2 q^i\right) (1-4 q)$ (while `TeXForm[StandardForm[Sum[q^n,{n,0,2}](1-4q)]]` still interchanges factors giving $(1-4 q) \left(1+q+q^2\right)$).

Clearly it is very annoying to have to change everything back into form I need by hand, especially with large expressions. Is there a way to tell the system to convert just the expression the way it is seen, without changing anything?

Comment: Will something silly like `TeXForm@DisplayForm@HoldForm[(1 + q + q^2) (1 - 4 q)]` work?

Comment: In what way does `HoldForm` not work exactly? I can't figure it out from your post. Do you mean that you want the summation expanded but the factors not reordered?

Comment: @march You are right it is not clear since I could not figure out how to give an explicit example. What happens in practice is this: I have rendered some huge expression and now see it in output form. Now I want to convert it to $\TeX$ using `HoldForm`. But issuing `TeXForm[HoldForm[%]]` just gives `\%`. Assigning some new symbol also does not work - if I say first `e=%` and then `TeXForm[HoldForm[e]]` this just gives `e`.

Comment: If you want expression to evaluate and use `HoldForm` just to prevent additional reordering done by `TeXForm`, then you can use `Evaluate`: `% // Evaluate // HoldForm // TeXForm`. If you want partial evaluation like in your example with `Sum`, then maybe making some operations `Inactive` combined with [`activeForm`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101520/14303) would work for you:  `Inactive[Times][Sum[q^n, {n, 0, 2}], (1 - 4 q)] // 
  activeForm // TeXForm`, it can be combined with `Evaluate // HoldForm` if needed.

Comment: @jkuczm Thank you, I will check asap. In the meanwhile - maybe it was not well formulated, what I want is to have $\TeX$ rendered exactly the way I see it in the output.

Comment: Unfortunately there are different mechanisms causing different discrepancies between output seen in the FrontEnd and in `TeXForm`, most likely I don't know all of them. By exactly as in the output you mean "really exactly", for example if you have `Sin[x]` you want result with capital "S" and square bracket, instead of "\sin (x)"?

Comment: @jkuczm No no, sorry, I again managed to formulate it imprecisely. By "exactly" I only mean "exactly in the same order".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there are two sources of reordering in examples from OP.

First is [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html) attribute of functions like `Plus` and `Times` which, in process of standard evaluation, sorts their arguments to canonical order.

```
q + 1 + q^2
(* Out[]= 1 + q + q^2 *)
```

Second is that [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html), which boxes are used internally by [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm.html), does additional reordering of sums and products.

```
1 + q + q^2
% // TraditionalForm
(* Out[]= 1 + q + q^2 *)
(* Out[]//TraditionalForm=
          q^2 + q + 1 *)
```

Both reorderings can be prevented by wrapping expression with [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html).

```
q + 1 + q^2 // HoldForm // TeXForm
(* Out[]//TeXForm=
          q+1+q^2 *)
```

---

If you have an already evaluated expression and you're satisfied with ordering in it, you can prevent additional reorderings, done by conversion to `TraditionalForm` boxes, by combining `HoldForm` with [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html).

```
1 + q + q^2
% // Evaluate // HoldForm // TeXForm
(* Out[]= 1 + q + q^2 *)
(* Out[]//TeXForm=
          1+q+q^2 *)
```

---

More complicated situation is when you want some sub-expressions to evaluate, but want to prevent some of reorderings that evaluation causes.
If you control creation of those expressions there are couple of ways to prevent such reorderings.

You could completely prevent evaluation (and thus reordering) of some instances of `Plus` or `Times` by wrapping them with [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html), let whole expression evaluate, then wrap result in `HoldForm`, then [`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html) and convert it.

```
Inactive[Times][Sum[q^n, {n, 0, 2}], (1 - 4 q)]
% // Evaluate // HoldForm // Activate
% // TeXForm
(* Out[]= (1 + q + q^2)*(1 - 4 q) *)
(* Out[]= (1 + q + q^2) (1 - 4 q) *)
(* Out[]//TeXForm=
          \left(1+q+q^2\right) (1-4 q) *)
```

Different approach is to locally "switch off" `Orderless` attribute of some functions.

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Times},
    ClearAttributes[Times, Orderless];
    Sum[q^n, {n, 0, 2}] (1 - 4 q) // Evaluate // HoldForm // TeXForm
]
(* Out[]//TeXForm=
          \left(1+q+q^2\right) (1-4 q) *)
```

---

If you already have an expression with some ordering you don't like, you can also ask *Mathematica* to reorder it afterward to desired order, but this requires teaching *Mathematica* what this desired order is.
See e.g. [How to sort arguments of Times in nonstandard order?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88740/14303)